# NGS Analysis: How can I extract the different variants in two VCF files

Tags: compare, bioinformatics, data-analysis, data-annotations, vcf-variant-call-format

I am currently working on my thesis and I am trying to analyze the results of NGS sequencing Illumina. I am not really familiar with bioinformatics and in this part of my project, I am trying two compare two vcf files corresponding to the results of healthy tissue and tumor tissue. I want to compare these vcf files and remove their similarities. More specifically I want to remove the information of the healthy tissue from the tumor one. Have you any suggestions on which tool I should use or any way that I can do my analysis? If you can help me I would be more than thankful. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I understand your problem. First thing I would recommend is to use Unix software  (I don't know which OS you're running) called [VCFtools](https://vcftools.github.io/index.html). It's pretty simple to use. But if You want to do all the processing with, for example python, you can use the `pandas` library for python which helps to process data in column format or `PyVCF` library, which is a parser for VCF files. I can help you more if you can provide some example data you're processing.